# Typescript SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' i am stuck with these error while declaring a variable?

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and visual studio code. I cannot able figure out whats going wrong, isn't it the problem arise because of installation of typescript in visual studio code.

for e.g. - students: number = 123

Please check the screenshot of the error.

[Please check the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvncA.png)

Comment: Please help i am stuck here, i had watched many videos on youtube and checked stackoverflow for solution but failed to solved this issue.

Comment: Please copy the error message as text and post it into the question. Use the `{}` button in the question editor toolbar to format the error or the code you put in the question.

Comment: [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html) is a language that is compiled to JavaScript. It cannot be executed as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending your code snippet with `const`, `var` or `let`:

`const students: number = 123;`